# gvim taglist current window

Tags: vim, taglist

Hi I am using gvim and the taglist plugin and I have several windows using splits, although when clicking a tag item with the mouse from the tag list window split, it seems that it goes to the window that the tag list item was first opened in. Is there a way to get it to use the current window that I click the mouse in? Usually I am opening code in a window split and then I want to click on another split window and have the tag data show up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of a double-click in the TagList window is the same as pressing the `<Enter>` key: It uses the plugin's *useopen* command, i.e. re-uses the (first) window where the file is already open.

There's another command, *prevwin*, which uses the previous window instead. By default, this is bound to the `P` key in the TagList window.

Comment: is there a list of these commands ?  It seems that 'o' will vert split a new window with the tag. Also is there a compliment to Ctrl-T to jump forward into the last tag after using ctrl-T so you can jump back and forth?

Comment: It says `Press <F1> to display help text` in the taglist window. Also, `:help taglist-using`.